# go-mysql/client Execute method blocks

Tags: mysql, go

I want to run a sql statement like `show BINLOG events in 'mysql-bin.000004' from 4 limit 1;` using [go-mysql/client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql/client#Conn.Execute)'s Execute method.

If the statement executes with no error, it works fine.

However, if I use a wrong event pos in the statement, like `show BINLOG events in 'mysql-bin.000004' from 5 limit 1;` (I will receive `Error when executing command SHOW BINLOG EVENTS: Wrong offset or I/O error` when I execute it in console), the method blocks.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The offset is a file offset of the binary log event. As no binary log event is 1 byte long, if position 4 is valid 5 will be invalid.

The binary log events position increments by the length of the previous event.

Comment: Yes I know, but I think it should return an error but not block there.

Comment: Opps, yes that was the main point. Does it block when using the same SQL on the `mysql` client? Which mysql server version? WHich go-mysql versions? Can you edit the question with these details and maybe a sample go program.